# Ruby on rails with paperclip

Tags: windows-8, window

I am a new programmer on ruby on rails, and i have problem when upload picture. Deos anyone can help me. thanks in advance.

class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_student, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /students
  # GET /students.json
  def index
    @students = Student.all
  end

# GET /students/1
  # GET /students/1.json
  def show
  end

# GET /students/new
  def new
    @student = Student.new
  end

# GET /students/1/edit
  def edit
  end

# POST /students
  # POST /students.json
  def create
    @student = Student.create(student_params)

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @student.save
    format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @student }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

private
    #def student_params
        #params.require(:student).permit(:image_file)
  #end

# PATCH/PUT /students/1
  # PATCH/PUT /students/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.update(student_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @student }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

# DELETE /students/1
  # DELETE /students/1.json
  def destroy
    @student.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to students_url, notice: 'Student was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_student
      @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    end

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def student_params
  params.require(:student).permit(:name, :gender, :telephone, :address)#, :image_file
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Can't really find a problem in your post. It's a bit hard to understand. Did you follow the docs on https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip? I take it your file attachment is in the Student model?

```
params.require(:student).permit(:name, :gender, :telephone, :address)#, :image_file
```

now you only permit to save name, gender, telephone and address, the image file wil not be saved. You still have to permit it.